# How to fix: "jarsigner.exe" exited with code 1 when creating .aab files for Google Play Store

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to deploy an app to the `Google Play Store` using the [new android app bundle formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/9/9.4#initial-support-for-android-app-bundle-publishing-format). However when following the `Developer-Command-Prompt` steps mentioned in previous link I get the following error:

```
(SignAndroidPackage target) (1:7) ->
(_Sign target) ->  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual  Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (3295,2):
error MSB6006: "jarsigner.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Since I followed the mentioned guide in the link above, I have

1. Added to my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

   ```
   android:installLocation="internalOnly"
   ```
2. Added to my `Android.csproj` file

   ```
   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
       <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
       ....
   </PropertyGroup>

   <PropertyGroup>
       <AndroidKeyStore>true</AndroidKeyStore>
       <AndroidSigningKeyStore>C:\Users\<my_sexy_name>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\Android License\Android License.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
       <AndroidSigningKeyStore>pwd</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
       <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>Android License</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
       <AndroidSigningKeyPass>pwd</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
       ....
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
3. Checked if the above files exist / the password is correct / ...
4. Checked the checkbox, and filled in the data under `Android Package Signing` in `Visual Studio`
5. Opened the `Developer Command Line Visual Studio 2019` and navigated to my Android-project location
6. Ran the following command (cfr. the link):

   ```
   msbuild -restore Android.csproj 
   -t:SignAndroidPackage 
   -p:Configuration=Release 
   -p:AndroidKeyStore=True 
   -p:AndroidSigningKeyStore="Android License.keystore" 
   -p:AndroidSigningStorePass="pwd"
   -p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias="Android License" 
   -p:AndroidSigningKeyPass="pwd"
   ```
7. Cried for several hours

Since the implementation of the `.aab files` is relatively new in `Visual Studio 2019` the how-to-handle-this-error-pages aren't that largely found when browsing `Google`

Any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to whom it might concern, I figured it out.
Turns out the `jarsigner.exe / powershell behind it` don't like spaces in the path (even tho they were parenthesised). So in my case, my `keystore file` is called `Android <space> License` so I renamed it to `Android_License`, updated in my `Visual Studio` and command and got a different error.

Comment: Cause: jarsigner.exefailed with exit code 1 :
jarsigner: attempt to rename..............
I am having the same problem but my directory paths do not possess spaces.